# monacaのtextareaの大きさを変える

Tags: monaca, jquery, css, onsen-ui

monacaの勉強を、参考プログラムのメモ帳を改造するところからはじめてます。
最初の状態だと、メモを書き込むtextareaがすごく狭いのですが、大きくする方法がわかりません。
CSSでは無理なのでしょうか？
わかる方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

cssが上手く適用されていないのではないでしょうか？
試しに`style.css`にこんな感じのを追加したら大きくなりました。

```
textarea#Memo
{
    height: 200px;
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]